# Use of the tag "Always-Friday-In -Iceland

Tags: discussion, tags

I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3553/if-apt-get-from-2020-existed-what-one-project-would-you-install) question and noticed that it was tagged with 'always-friday-in-iceland, I couldnt catch the reason behind creating that tag and also its Usage/meaning, kindly elucidate.

Comment: This tag should [never be used ever again](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/284/fun-thread-friday)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The same question has been asked on [StackOverflow Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36918/always-friday-in-iceland). Here is the answer that was provided there:

> That started with the user [Olafur Waage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22459/olafur-waage) who lives in Iceland. I
>   believe it started with someone asking a Friday type of fun question
>   and it started as a comment, then turned into a tag. And then people
>   started slapping it on more fun meta questions.
>
> Friday is kind of the official "[let a few fun questions survive on
>   meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/21413#21413)" relaxed day. I believe someone asked a fun type of question
>   and it was not Friday and someone's defense was it is always Friday in
>   Iceland!

Comment: pretty long history i should say, iceland:P